# Seekbar not handling touch events

Tags: android

I used seekbar in my application to show audio track position. When the activity is
started the first time, it is working fine. It is handling touch events, the audio is forwarded or backwarded according to the touch events and the seekbar shaded portion is shown too. That means it is working fine...

But when the activity goes to the background and again returns to the foreground and I try to move the seekbar manually, the song position is forwarded and backwarded according to touch events but the seekbar shaded region is not updated by the touch events from the user...

Why it is so?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.audioplayer);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.audioplayerlayout);
    layoutui1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.audiolayoutui1);
    layoutui2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.audiolayoutui2);
    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    volControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbarVolume);
    volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
    muteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mutebutton);
    muteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    muteButton.setBackgroundColor(color.transparent);
    setwakeupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WakeupAlarmButtom);
    setwakeupButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
    play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnplay);
    // view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progressview);
    bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbartrack);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textview.setText("");
    // listeners...
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    play.setBackgroundColor(color.transparent);
    application = (videoplayerapplication) getApplication();
    application.play();
    volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressvol,
                boolean fromUser) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    progressvol, 50);
        }
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });

    {
        duration = (application.getDuration() / 1000);
        d = (int) (duration);
        Log.v("duraton .....", "" + d);
        bar.setMax(d);
        countdown(d);
        Log.v("The value of keeptrack", "" + toKeepTrackValue);
    }
    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // check whether the user has touched the bar
            if (fromUser) {
                application.seekforward(progress);
                i = progress;
                prog = progress;
                count.cancel();
                countdown((application.getDuration() / 1000) - progress);
            }
        }
    });
}
public void countdown(double convert) {
    count = new CountDownTimer((long) (convert * 1000), 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisecond) {
            conversion = millisecond;
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            b.append("" + conversion / 60000);
            newposition=(int) (conversion / 60000);
            textview.setText(b.substring(0, 4));
            bar.setProgress((int) (conversion / 60000));
            if (toKeepTrackValue == false) {
                bar.setProgress(i++);
            }
            if (toKeepTrackValue == true) {
                Log.v("the getseekpos", "" + getSeekPosition);
                bar.setProgress(getSeekPosition++);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // finish......
            bar.setProgress(0);
            i = 0;
            textview.setText(" 0.0");
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            checkAudioTrackFinish = 2;
            textview.setText(" 26:46");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Try to override seek Bar class,set position of your video/audio in override method and implement correct logic to OnResume method.

Answer (score 0):

it is probably due to no SaveState of SeekBar object implemented. Like there is no onConfigurationChanged(newConfig) implementation.